# Java math problems - Vote count to percentage

Tags: java, math

```
private static int votePercentage() {
    int players = 0;
    for (int p = 0; h < PLAYERS; p++) {
        if (playersOnline[p] != null) {
            players++;
        }
    }
    int votes = voters.size();
    int avg = (votes / players);
    return (avg * 100);
}
```

Votes: 1
Players: 2
return: 0

Votes: 2
Players: 2
return: 100

**Problem**

The problem is, that the returning nubmer is not an int, and is a double because 1/2 = 0.5.
Therefore it will always return 0, unless the votes division by players is not a double and is a int.

Basically I want to return the percent of the voted users, out of all online players.

Is there a solution for this? maybe a java class or built-in function?

Comment: `return ((votes * 100) / players);`?

Comment: @devnull I tried it, its not the problem.

Comment: -1. What are `playersOnline`, `voters`, and `PLAYERS`?  How are you getting the numbers that you print?  But most annoying, if your problem is truly that you needed `float`s instead of `int`s, then devnull's answer would have worked just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `float` (remember to change the function's return type!):

```
float avg = ((float)votes / players);
```

`int` can only store integers; it cannot store decimals. Only `float` and `double` (for double precision) can store decimal numbers.

You could also switch around your formula:

```
return ((votes * 100) / players);
```

Note that this will round down to the next integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use integers:

```
int avg = votes * 100 / players;
return avg;
```

But it would be best to switch to `float` or `double` for precision.